# Create tables with php for

Tags: php, for-loop

I need to create 3 tables with 10 columns and 5 rows that display numbers from 1 to 50, and I need to generate 3 combinations of random numbers with 6 tens from 1 to 50 and define the numbers drawn in the table in red.

So far so good, I created a for to display the tables and within that for I created a function to display the numbers from 1 to 50.

```
for ($r = 1; $r <4; $r++) {

echo "<p> Result:". $ r. PHP_EOL;
echo "<table> <tr>
        <th> 1 </th>
        <th> 2 </th>
        <th> 3 </th>
        <th> 4 </th>
        <th> 5 </th>
        <th> 6 </th>
        <th> 7 </th>
        <th> 8 </th>
        <th> 9 </th>
        <th> 10 </th>
    </tr> ";

for ($d = 1; $d <51; $d) {
    if ($d%10 == 1) {
        echo "<tr>". PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo "<td>". $ d ++. "</td>". PHP_EOL;

    if ($d%10 == 1) {
        echo "</tr>". PHP_EOL;
    }
}

echo "</table>";

}
```

The function you were using to generate the random numbers:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <7; $i++) {
    $result[] = rand(1, 50);

    for ($b = 0; $b <count ($result); $b++) {

    }
}
```

My problem is that I am not able to define the numbers drawn in the respective tables.

The complete code is here> https://hastebin.com/kosuvirofu.bash

Comment: fix your variable declaration first. there should no space after $

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you wanted to modify your code so that each table cell contains **a random number between 1-50**, then it is a simple matter of replacing this line:

```php
echo "<td>" . $d++ . "</td>" . PHP_EOL;
```

With this:

```php
echo "<td>" . rand(1, 50) .  "</td>" . PHP_EOL;
$d++;
```

Which results in [this example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUGzw.png).